# Recursion loop for parent checkbox to check all children checkboxes ztree

Tags: jquery, recursion, checkbox, ztree

I use jquery.ztree.all-3.5.js in my application. I want to make a recursive loop for parent checkbox to check all child checkboxes but I can not perform this?

Is there a solution for this problem in ztree? I can't find a solution and I cannot change the tree plugin in the application.